# codeigniter sessions issue on Chrome

Tags: codeigniter, session

I have a seriuos problem with codeigniter sessions using database, on Chrome:
when i use chrome developers tool and i refresh the page , the session is destroyed.

This my session config:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE; 
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'cisessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Have you any idea about that ?

Comment: Are your database settings correct?  Check them, and also check if there is data in the `ci_session` table.

Comment: I solved it, i changed $config['sess_match_useragent'] to FALSE,

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that the session is destroyed? I think that it's just not getting updated as supposed and it creates a new one on every page request. (common Codeigniter's setting issue)

**here's my suggestions:**

double check your Application/Config/config.php file to ensure that the part of session domain looks like that if you host the site on the main directory:

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "yourdomain.com";
$config['cookie_path']  = "var/sessions/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

and like that if you host the site on a sub-directory:

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "yourdomain.com";
$config['cookie_path']  = "siteSubDirectory/var/sessions/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

and also make sure that the 2 directories are writable by fixing their permissions to 755 or so, and I strongly recommend that you enable database session, it's more secure and will help you find out the real problem by checking the session table. good luck :)